# How to maintain the UserID, Name, Dept and Role of a User during his Visit to the Site?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

What is the good practice to maintain the UserID, Name, Dept and Role of a User during his Visit to the Site ? Should i store it in session? Bcz the session will expire after 20min... Or is it OK if i store this in the Hidden labels of the Master Page?

Comment: _"Because the session will expire after 20 minutes"_ - you do realize the session timeout is a window that's being reset after each page view?

Comment: You have httpruntime cache as one option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Where do you store information that has to last for the duration of the users session?

That's exactly what [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) was designed for, the docs state you should "*Use ASP.NET session state to store and retrieve values for a user*"

> the session will expire after 20 min

Yes, but after 20 mins of *inactivity* which generally means the user is no longer using/browsing the site...or in other words, has left the site.

Comment: Thank U, I was not aware that its " 20 mins of inactivity!" if it is so then no problem!